# Postgis Spatial query using pyqis between two spatial table

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

I try to query two spatial table using st_within function, then I want to display the query result as a QGIS Layer. But the layer did not add to the QGIS Canvas.
Here my code :

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_pbb' host=localhost port=5433 user='postgres' password='septin'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT wa FROM gis.kecamatan""")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    row_list = []
    for row in rows:
        #row_list.append(row.)
        self.dlg.cboKecamatan.addItems([row[0]])
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    text = str(self.dlg.cboKecamatan.currentText())
    txtnop = self.dlg.lineNOP.text()

    # See if OK was pressed
    if result == 1:
        #Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        #Versi satu - sudah berhasil, yeay, you know the key right ?

        sql = "(SELECT gis.tm_bidang.numb, st_within(gis.tm_bidang.geom,gis.kec_palu_utm.geom) as within_geom, gis.tm_bidang.d_nop,gis.tm_bidang.d_luas, gis.tm_bidang.aktor from gis.tm_bidang,gis.kec_palu_utm where gis.kec_palu_utm.wa = '"+text+"' and st_within(gis.tm_bidang.geom,gis.kec_palu_utm.geom))"
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        uri.setConnection("localhost", "5433", "db_pbb", "postgres", "septin")
        uri.setDataSource("", sql, "within_geom", "", "numb")
        tmadminkec = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "tm_bidang", "postgres")
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(tmadminkec)
```

Any ideas ?,

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying something similar and want to be able to send a query. Somehow that does not seem to be working even though the documentation for setDataSource() provides several parameters.

I had to change my code to the below to display a simple WHERE clause but still haven't figured out how to display a custom query without only specifying the where clause.

```
uri.setDataSource(*schema*, *table*, *geom colum*, *where clause*")
```

EDIT: Think I just solved it. Hopefully it works for you. I was testing this using the global flow visualisation from here with airports and routes, https://anitagraser.com/2011/08/20/visualizing-global-connections/

Based on trial/error/research, it seems like for the `setDataSource` function the you dont pass the schema and pass the sql string as the parameter for the table.

Check here as well,
https://georepublic.info/en/blog/2013/joining-tables-with-sql-using-pyqgis/

The code I used is below,

```
sql = "(select * from routes where source_airport in ('BKK', 'DXB', 'KUL'))"
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection('localhost', '5432', 'postgis_test', 'postgres', 'xxx')
uri.setDataSource("", sql, "geom", "", "gid")
print uri.uri()
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "test", "postgres")

if not vlayer.isValid():
    print "not valid"

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```